# Selling an application that scrapes Google, Bing, Yahoo

Tags: internet, software

Is it legal to sell an application that scrapes search results from several search engines and uses this information for the application functionality?

- Application is sold to people for their personal use, interest
- Scrapes happen inside the application, they are not done by a  cloud service of any kind, it is a standalone application

Let us say functionality is similar to:

http://www.scrapebox.com/search-engine-scraper

Comment: Very interesting question!!!  I manually scraped some engines and found this discussion on BlackHatWorld:
 https://www.blackhatworld.com/seo/how-has-scrapebox-not-been-sued-by-google.749214/

Comment: Thanks for that! I made quite a bit of searching on this topic but did not see this thread before...
As for the contents, it seems to me, people dance around the TOS, Fair use policy, robots.txt, but I feel like no one really has an actual idea of what is going on. Perhaps I am asking a question that has no clear answer... Which is sort of an answer in its own.

Comment: I'm dealing with the chaos of software and algorithmic patents myself, and as far as I can tell, nobody knows what's going on with that, including the experts.  I personally find it absurd that one would be restricted from using publicly available data scraped from search engines, regardless of how that may be being abused by unscrupulous actors, but "that and 2 cents will get you a cup of coffee, as the saying goes. ;)

Comment: It is interesting that there don't seem to be any lawsuits regarding this technique, which *may* be an indicator of legality. In the US, cease-and-desist letter usually provide an escape hatch prior to litigation (litigation is so expensive, it's always more cost effective not to have to sue, particularly if the presumed infringer doesn't have significant assets.  That said, consult with an attorney who specialized in this field.  Consultations are free.